# Dense subspace of radial functions of $H^1(\mathbb{R}^N)$

Tags: partial-differential-equations, sobolev-spaces, elliptic-equations, fractional-sobolev-spaces

By definition the space of radial functions in $H^1(\mathbb{R}^N)$ is
$$
H^1_{rad}(\mathbb{R}^N) = \{u \in H^1(\mathbb{R}^N) : u = u \circ R, \forall R \in O(N)\}.
$$
I'm trying to find a dense subspace of it. I suspect that the required subspace is
$$
C^{\infty}_{0,rad}(\mathbb{R}^N) = \{u \in C^\infty_{0}(\mathbb{R}^N) : u = u \circ R, \forall R \in O(N)\}.
$$
I know how to show that $\overline{C^{\infty}_{0,rad}(\mathbb{R}^N)}^{H^1(\mathbb{R}^N)} \subset H^1_{rad}(\mathbb{R}^N)$. To prove the reverse inclusion I tried to use that $C^\infty_0(\mathbb{R}^N)$ is dense in $H^1(\mathbb{R}^N)$. However I got stuck.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The same proof as for Sobolev spaces will work:

1. Take $\phi_k(x):= \phi(x/k)$, for some radial $\phi\in C_c^\infty(\mathbb{R}^N)$ with $\phi\equiv 1$ on the unit ball, supported in $B(0,2)$, and $0\leq \phi \leq 1$ throughout. Set $w_k=w\cdot \phi_k$. Using the product rule you can check that $\| w-w_k\|_{H^1}\to 0$ as $k\to \infty$.
2. By 1, compactly supported, radial, $H^1$ functions are dense. To finish, approximate these by convolving with a *radial* mollifier (convolution of radial functions is radial).

Comment: How the proof should be if we change $\mathbb{R}^N$ by a bounded domain $\Omega$ and $H^1$ by $H^1_0$ ?

Comment: @ThiagoGM: Are we talking still about radial functions? If so, said bounded domain would have to be a ball

Comment: Yes, I am talking about radial functions.

Comment: @ThiagoGM: Off the top of my head (i.e. I haven't checked in detail!), I propose the following: Let $u\in H_0^1(B)$ (where $B$ is a ball centered at the origin) and $u$ radial. By definition of the space, for each $k\in \mathbb{N}$ there exists $v_k\in C_c^\infty(B)$ with $\| u-v_k\|_{H^1}<1/k$. Define $u_k(x):= \int_{O(n)} v_k(Ax)\, dm(A)$, where $dm(A)$ denotes the Haar measure on the group of orthogonal transformations (It's a probability measure, invariant under multiplication by elements of $O(n)$), then $u_k\in C_c^\infty(B)$ is radial and $\| u-u_k\|_{H^1}\lesssim \| u-v_k\|_{H^1}$.

Comment: The definition of $u_k$ may seem technical at first, but here's a motivating example: Suppose we want to approximate an **even** function $u\in H_0^1$. Let $v_k$ as above. The easiest way to turn $v_k$ into an even function is by defining $u_k(x):= \frac{1}{2}(v_k(x)+v_k(-x))$ and since $u(x)=\frac{1}{2}(u(x)+u(-x))$, then we can use that each summand in $u_k$ approximates well the corresponding summand in $u$ and we're done. We can look at this example as the $H_0^1$ space that's invariant under the group $\{ I_n, -I_n\}$, where the Haar measure is just counting measure. Cont.

Comment: For the more general group $O(n)$ the Haar measure is more complicated, but the idea for constructing $u_k$ from $v_k$ is the same, except this time instead of sums we use integrals since our group is much larger.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. This proof only works for a ball ?

Comment: I liked a lot of your answer. Could you please tell me a good reference that deals with integrals relating to Haar measure on the group of orthogonal transformations ?

Comment: @ThiagoGM: No, any domain invariant under the whole group $O(n)$ will work as well, with the same proof (e.g. an annulus). As for a reference, I'd say Folland's "A course in abstract harmonic analysis" is a good place to start.